# Assign full array to destructuring variable

Tags: javascript, destructuring

In Clojure destructuring it's possible to also have a binding for the full array using `:as`, is something similar possible in Javascript?

For example,

```js
const queue = [[1, 2]];
const [x, y :as pos] = queue.shift();
```

where `x` would be 1, `y` would be 2 and `pos` would be `[1, 2]`?

or is an extra in-between step necessary, like

```js
const queue = [[1, 2]];
const pos = queue.shift();
const [x, y] = pos;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the parent and nested properties at the same time during destructuring.

I'd do it separately for readability

```js
const queue = [ [1, 2] ],
      pos = queue.shift(),
      [x, y] = pos;
```

BUT, it is possible to do it in single line. If you destructure the array like an object. Get the `0` property to a variable and destructure the nested array

```js
const queue = [ [1, 2] ];

const { 0: pos, 0: [x, y] } = queue

console.log(x, y)
console.log(pos)
```

Comment: The first snippet, put the shift back in, and it's what the OP has already done.

Comment: @Keith yeah, but it is not mutating the array and is in a single declaration.

Comment: It's a queue, it's likely it wants to be mutated.. :)

Comment: @Keith ah, yes. Didn't put too much thought into the variable name

Comment: Thanks. Nice usage of the indices, but unfortunately it's not the same since the array is not mutated afterwards as noted by Keith. The `shift()` returns `[1, 2]` and then that I want to destructure into `x`, `y` and `pos`.

Comment: @user2609980 Then the answer is `const pos = queue.shift(), [x, y] = pos`. You can't get the array to a new variable while simultaneously destructuring it. It's not possible in javascript

Comment: @adiga thanks, at least using the `,` syntax one `const` can be removed.